# Magento 1.9: Opinions about my real-time form validation check

Tags: magento-1.9, validation

I have created a `"real-time"` form `validation` check like so:

```
 var validstreet1 = function(){
 Validation.validate($('street_1'));
  };

$('street_1').on('focus',function() {

interval1 = setInterval(validstreet1, 1500);

});

$('street_1').on('blur',function() {
  clearInterval(interval1);  
});
```

So basically, when the `address field` is in focus, the form validation gets updated every `1.5 seconds` (as opposed to only when `"save"` button is clicked). this creates a really nice `" real-time "` effect.

I am wondering if this won't create too much stress on the system.

Comment: JQuery runs on client side, how will it create stress on the system? or if by system you mean user's system, still it doesn't load system that much. "I Guess"

Comment: Well, I have never seen this being done before, despite how intuitive it is, so I got suspicious and thought there must be a reason..

Comment: there are many sites which apply validation on key up (on each key press) and I will suggest it to you also, instead of waiting for 1.5 sec, why not invoke validation on each keypress.

Comment: I actually tried doing that, but I had a problem, when typing fast, the error message would flicker and sometimes not display at all...

Comment: Just found this: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/48268/validate-on-blur-or-keypress